# Customizing / subclassing UICollectionViewLayout to enable scrolling in multiple directions

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm designing a layout for my app that is going to take advantage of `UICollectionView`. I have created some moderately complex `collectionView`-based apps before, but I may need to subclass the layout class for this one. The main point I'm trying to figure out is whether I can have different sections of the same `collectionView` scroll in different directions.

Based on what I have read and tried so far, the only way to have one section scroll horizontally and another vertically would be by using multiple nested instances of `UICollectionView`.

This is a basic idea of my layout. My guess is that even with subclassing, a single `UICollectionView` would not be able to handle it. Or would it?

[image: Multiple directions of scrolling]

Comment: Are section 0 and section 1 actual collection view sections or just cells ?

Comment: Sections, with multiple cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it with a custom [`UICollectionViewLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html) but I'd use the default flow layout with one cell containing something like a SwipeView for the section 0 and other cells in your section 1.